# Catch if someone tries to set a class instance's variable directly

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, instance

Assume that I have a class which requires pre-treatment of an input variable `x`. Towards this end, I have implemented a function within this class to set the variable (including the pre-treatment). To fool-proof the algorithm, I would like to know whether there is a way to catch attempts of users trying to set `x` manually, instead of calling the correct function. As a small dummy example, consider the following:

```
class dummy(): 
    def __init__(self, x):
        # This function initializes the instance
        self.x = x
    
    def adjust_x(self):
        # This function makes some change to x
        self.x += 5
        
    def set_x(self, x):
        # This function initializes x correctly
        self.x = x
        self.adjust_x()
        
instance = dummy(3)
print('Initialized correctly, the value of x is: ' + str(instance.x))

# We can also set x later on, using the correct function
instance.set_x(3)
print('Calling the function to set x, we get: ' + str(instance.x))

# However, if the user would try to set x directly, the variable does not get
# correctly adjusted:
instance.x = 3
print('Direct setting: ' + str(instance.x) + ' (/= 8, because instance.adjust_x() was not called)')
```

Is there a way to catch someone using `instance.x` to set `x`? I'd like to raise an error or a warning in that situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you can restrict the access of an attribute (that's the equivalent of setting the access modifier of a field to private) by prepending a double underscore to the attribute.

#### Example

```
class Object():
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.__name = name
```

Trying to access `instance.name` or `instance.__name` would raise an `AttributeError`.

#### Note

As @mkrieger1 pointed out, the double underscores were not *meant* to prevent access but I find it that it works. More about private variables in Python can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables).

Comment: Double underscores are not meant to prevent access, they are meant to prevent accidentally overwriting the variable of a parent class in a subclass.

Comment: I see. Can you recommend a better way to prevent access?

Comment: @J.Galt As far as *I* know, there isn't another way to prevent access. You can read more about private variables in the official Python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables).